# Avada theme wordpress customization

Tags: php, html

I need help adding a company phone number above the nav menu in the header for the Avada theme. Below is the code for the header.php in avada theme `[code missing, forgot to add]`.

Also can someone tell me where to add the phone number in the code so it shows up above the nav bar on the header in theme?  can anybody else hep me?

Comment: What code do you have? Please post

Comment: Where is the code for header.php?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the code.

However, based on this demo: http://demo.theme-fusion.com/
and the limited info you're giving me, I'm guessing that you want the phone number above the top nav. If so, then do as follows:

```
#nav {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
#phone {
    float: right;
    margin: 40px 15px -40px 0;
    font-family: MuseoSlab500Regular, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Find:

```
<div class="logo" ... </div>
```

add a div after:

```
<div class="logo" ... </div><div id="phone">888-888-8888</div>
```

Now you have a phone number above the top nav bar! Enjoy!

p.s. if you implemented correctly it should look like this now:

[image]

Comment: here is the code below for the header.php I cant find where it says div id="logo

Comment: it's probably located in index.php then. Search all the pages. If not then back up all the files to your PC, open all in notepad++, and use advanced search to track down where the code is. It also might be in a menu page, look for something like menu.php or something similar.

Comment: where would I find it in header.php of avada theme?

Comment: If it's not IN header.php then obviously you can't find it in there, it is in another file then. Do what I suggested above.

Comment: is there a way I can send you the code and you can tell me where to add the code please?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without theme coding. the Avada theme has five different headers. You can select the different header style in the theme options.

- Login in wordpress
- Go to "Avada" on the right menu
- Go to "theme options"
- Go to "Header" en choose "Header options"
- Choose a style with the phone number above the navigation bar.
- scroll down to "Phone Number For Contact Info" and provide phone number
- Go to "Custom css" and add:

  .fusion-contact-info {
   float: right;
  }