# add phone number in avada headline on the right side

Tags: php, html, wordpress, themes, customization

I'm trying to add a phone number on the right side of the header using avada theme, I saw a this post and it looks like it would solve the problem Im having [Avada theme wordpress customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429083/avada-theme-wordpress-customization) , but I cant find 
`<div class="logo">` in wardpress appearance editor. Where could i find this line or is there an easier way of implementing what I want.

Comment: I'm trying to add a phone number on the right side of the header using avada theme, I saw a this post and it looks like it would solve the problem Im having http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429083/avada-theme-wordpress-customization , but I cant find <div class="logo" in wordpress appearance editor. Where could i find this line or is there an easier way of implementing what I want?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to do something like this: http://prntscr.com/6r8wyc
In order to add a phone number you have to go to Avada Theme Options -> Header -> Select the header layout according to your needs

Once the header is selected scroll down a little and start to add the information (ex: phone number, email, etc..)